# Does the default classloader in java keep everything in memory or leave in file system?

Tags: java, jar, classloader, dynamic-loading, dynamic-class-loaders

I wonder when you have a jar, dynamically loaded in your running program, do all the content (classes, resources) in the jar be stored somewhere in the VM memory?

So that everytime you need to access the class or a text resource file (e.g. via getClass().getResourceAsStream), it can be pulled quickly from memory rather than to access the jar in file system again? i.e. you can delete the jar after that.

Sorry but if I am asking a wrong question, please change my question into explaining the classloader process as I may misunderstood it, in particular for the resources packed in the jar. Thank you.

Comment: It may be implementation specific so some JVMs may do it and some don't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, normally resources are not loaded from disk until you access them.

Classes are loaded into memory and stay in memory after their first use. Resources are not cached at the JVM or JRE level - every time you call `getResourceAsStream` you get a new stream from disk.

Comment: But in theory there is no rule that prevents the JVM from pre-loading several class files at once, is there? (I'm talking about caching file content, not loading and resolving the classes themselves)

Comment: As for your "resources are not loaded from disk until you access them", are you suggesting that the resources can be cached in memory once you accessed them?

Comment: @user1589188 No, only classes keep in memory after they have been loaded once. Resources are never explicitely cached, but of course they might still be in memory due to hard disk caching.

Comment: @[isnot2bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573578/does-the-default-classloader-in-java-keep-everything-in-memory-or-leave-in-file#comment45456892_28573606): the JVM is free to preload classes; in principle, even loading and resolving eagerly is allowed by the specification. In practice, the HotSpot implementation uses memory mapping for the [shared class data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html) of the JRE implementation, so the underlying system will (pre)load them on a block/memory segment basis.